# Use PHP to search directorys for files recursively and change values

Tags: php, html, css, var

I have some php that's replacing color values in css files in a directory. It works fine except that it only searches for css files in the main directory. I've been searching but cant seem to find a simple way to make this recursive. Any ideas?

I'm currently using $arr=glob("themes/Evolution/*.css");

An example folder structure with css files are.

```
Main Dir > Style.css
Main Dir > Folder 1 > mycss.css
Main Dir > Folder 2 > mycss.css
Main Dir > Folder 3 > mycss.css
```

```html
//Read default color from INI
$lines_array = file("modules/evolution/evolution.ini");
$search_string = "currentcolor";

foreach($lines_array as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false) {
       list(, $new_str) = explode("=", $line);
          $new_str = trim($new_str); //This line removes the spaces before and after.
    }
}

$inicurrentcolor = $new_str;

//code to change css color
if(isset($_REQUEST['resetcolor'])){
 $arr=glob("themes/Evolution/*.css"); //your css file's path
  $textboxdefaultcolorcode=$_POST['defaultcolor']; 
  
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
 $str=file_get_contents($val);
   $str=str_replace($inicurrentcolor, $textboxdefaultcolorcode, $str); 
  file_put_contents($val, $str);
 }
}

<div class="colorbox">
<br>
<label id="steps">Reset Evolution theme color back to the default color.</label>
<br>
<br>
<Form name="default1" method="POST" action="home.php?m=evolution">
<label for="color1">Default Theme Color: </label><input style="background-color:#379BB9; color:#ffffff" type="text" id="defaultcolor" name="defaultcolor" value="#379BB9" readonly>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="resetcolor" value="Reset Theme Color">
</form>
<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer with some help. The code below will allow you to search recursively with the code above. Hope this helps.

```html
$themedir = 'themes/Evolution';
$allFiles = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($themedir));
$cssFiles = new RegexIterator($allFiles, '/\.css$/i');

if(isset($_REQUEST['resetcolor'])){
$textboxdefaultcolorcode=$_POST['defaultcolor']; //added line

foreach($cssFiles as $cssFile=>$val){
 $str=file_get_contents($val);
   $str=str_replace($inicurrentcolor, $textboxdefaultcolorcode, $str); 
  file_put_contents($val, $str);
 }
}
```